# Is it possible to colorize output piped to more?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, pipe

I have `ls` and `grep` aliased to `ls --color=auto` and `grep --color=auto` for colorized output, but when I pipe to more the color is lost.

Neither `more` nor `less` seems to have a param for colorizing their output.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem isn't that `more` and `less` aren't colourizing their output, it's that `ls` is not outputting the colour because it's connected to another process rather than the terminal.

You can't easily get `ls` to be any smarter about when it outputs colour, but you can add `--color` to force it to output colour when you're piping it to `more`

When you have colour output, use `... |less -R` to make `less` pass the colours through to the terminal instead of showing the escape codes as text

Comment: Ideally you want `less -R` rather than `less -r`.

Comment: thanks @jørgensen, I just re-read the man page and agree. updated above.

Comment: If you're on a Mac (OS X 10.9 at least) you'll have to use `--color=always` (for grep), CLICOLOR_FORCE=true env variable for ls etc. to get the commands to spit out color codes even when the receiver is not a terminal.

Answer (score 4):

```
ls --color | less -r
```

Tested on Linux, GNU userland.

Comment: Thanks, that works too.  I'd give you the green check too if I could, but je4d beat you by just a few seconds.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the thanks :-) je4d's answer is also much more comprehensive, so IMO he deserves the tick.

Answer (score 2):

On macOS 10.15 Catalina (darwin 19.0.0) you can colorize the output of `ls` piped to `head`, `grep`, `less` and `more` with the following adjustments to your zsh config:

**~/.zshrc**

```sh
alias less="less -R"
alias more="more -R"
```

**~/.zshenv**

```sh
export GREP_COLOR=always
export CLICOLOR_FORCE=true
```

Run `open x-man-page://command` to open the man page for the command `command`.